# <Permission denied> error trying to instantiate web worker object

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

Trying out the web worker API for the first time and can't seem to get a response from the background worker.

Markup:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/script.js"></script>
<button onclick="TriggerWorker()">Trigger Worker</button>
```

Contents of script.js file:

```
function TriggerWorker() {

    var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');

    myWorker.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }

    console.log(myWorker);

    myWorker.postMessage("Text sent to worker");
}
```

Contents of worker.js file:

```
onmessage = function (e) {
    postMessage('OK');
}
```

I can get the myWorker object to write to the console, but the response "OK" never makes it back into the console. When inspecting the myWorker object, I can see that the onmessage property is set to "Permission denied".

Comment: where is your worker class?

Comment: is the worker loaded when you send it a message? log something on load   and see if that works...

Comment: @noob No other declaration in the worker.js file. Should this be in a function called Worker()?

Comment: @dandavis Nothing in the console when I try this, but as I understand it, the worker is loaded with a different scope so wasn't sure if it would actually have access to the console. Maybe I'm not actually getting into the worker.js file...

Comment: i mean send a message from the worker right away, onload or even just at the bottom. sending messages that go nowhere doesn't leave any obvious trace like an error. i suspect your message that triggers the OK message arrives before the worker's onmessage handler is bound...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path of the file containing the worker onmessage declaration is relative to the html file - not the calling script file.

I got it working by making the following edit:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('../Scripts/worker.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The onmessage event pertains to the current window. So in script.js it should be

   self.onmessage = function (e)

instead of

```
myWorker.onmessage = function (e)
```

2. The postMessage method pertains to the target window. So in worker.js it should be

   onmessage = function (e) {
        e.source.postMessage('OK'); }

instead of

```
onmessage = function (e) {
   postMessage('OK'); }
```