# Web Worker onMessage/onError is "permission denied" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-worker

Foremost, I would like to say that my Web worker setup **works in** both **Google Chrome** and **MS Edge**. The same code that works in both these browsers does not work in IE 11.

Is there any nuance in IE 11 that I am not seeing? I already googled plenty and nothing relevant has come up.

So here's my logic on the main page:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('some-worker.js');
myWorker.onmessage = function(evt) {
                if (evt.data=="task1_result") {

                    //do something    

                }  else if (evt.data[0]=="task2_result") {

                    //do something with evt.data[1], which is an array

                } else { //something else }

            }
```

then on the `some-worker.js` file:

```
importScripts('some-file.js');
importScripts('some-file2.js');

onmessage = function(e) {    
    if(e.data[0] == "do_task1") {

         //do something then
          self.postMessage(["task1_result",some-data]);

    } else if(e.data[0] == "do_task2"){

        //do something then
        self.postMessage(["task2_result",[data_in_array]]);

    } else { //something else} 
};
```

**ISSUE:**  When I load my page in IE 11, `myWorker` doesn't even return the result of task1 (note that it will always return a value). There is no explicit error being thrown in the console.

So when I checked the `myWorker` object, I get the following:

[image]

Again, the above worker setup works in both Chrome and Edge.  Is there anything I'm missing to consider in IE 11?

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: ive revised the question. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that IE has nothing special with using Web Worker. You could check the result of `evt.data` and check if you use something not compatible with IE in `some-file.js` and `some-file2.js`. You could refer to the [sample of web worker](https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker), it works in IE11. I also find a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654203/permission-denied-error-trying-to-instantiate-web-worker-object), you could check it to see if you have the same issue. If the issue still occurs it could be better if you share a simple sample which helps reproduce it.

Comment: that makes sense. i'll do some further checking thanks. In the meantime, i've excluded ie in my webapp.